# I'm having trouble using sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates, update-manager

When I type `sudo apt update` on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine it gives me a failed to find ppa for steam but I checked my ppa's under update manager and I couldn't find the ppa that was giving me a problem. What should I do?

[image: The image is my terminal when I enter sudo apt update]

Comment: the problem is in steam repo, the error message says so

Comment: Did you try to update again?

Comment: It may be an issue with your DNS - have you tried using a different DNS resolver (e.g. CloudFlare, OpenDNS)? Furthermore, if you edited the /etc/hosts file to override the default steam IP address, this would be an issue.

Comment: Is this an existing configuration that worked previously? Or a new config? Observation: I see you have an IPv6 address for steam. Is that an issue?

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I found the solution! Since I downloaded steam directly from the website, I think it did not download the repo that was being troublesome so I ran a 'sudo apt-get install steam' and everything worked!